# Failed to deploy project. For more information, query the operation_messages view for the operation identifier '20132'?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, deployment, ssis, package

The Packages was deployed fine Initially , i have made few changes and try to deploy it again. i am receiving the following Error:

> Failed to deploy project. For more information, query the operation_messages view for the operation identifier '20132'

When I query the SSIS DB with `select * from catalog.operations_messages` no rows are returned, just column headers are showing in the Data. Please help

Comment: Any chance you lack permissions? Most things in the SSISDB require sysadmin or ssisadmin role (2016 has new roles for viewing logs but I don't recall the name)

Comment: Thanks for the Reply.
I have all the permissions, But still there is no Luck, still deploying the package is failing and when i am executing catalog.operation_messages, it wasn't showing anything.

Any other possibilities, Please help 

Many Thanks,

Comment: Just to verify `SELECT TOP 1 * FROM SSISDB.catalog.operation_messages` yields nothing?

Comment: I tried this SELECT TOP 1 * FROM SSISDB.catalog.operation_messages still it wasn't showing anything

Answer (score 1):

Closing the visual studio and reopening it solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

**First**, Refering to this [Microsoft Link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/system-views/catalog-operation-messages-ssisdb-database), This view requires one of the following permissions:

- READ permission on the operation
- Membership to the ssis_admin database role
- Membership to the sysadmin server role

Check that you have the right permissions to access this view

**Second**, The `SSISDB.catalog.operation_messages` table stores the package execution log. If there is no package executed on this server, the `SSISDB.catalog.operation_messages` table will be empty.

And the package deployment log is stored in  `[internal].[packages]` table and `[internal].[projects]` table

You can use a similar query to read info from these tables:

```
select * from internal.packages a inner join internal.projects b on a.project_id = b.project_id
```

Comment: Hi Hadi,

Thanks for the Reply.

I have refereed the provided Link and followed the steps you mentioned , But still there is no Luck, still deploying the package is failing and when i am executing catalog.operation_messages, it wasn't showing anything.

Any other possibilities, Please help 

Many Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

have a look at your **SQL Server Logs**

Yesterday I had a similar issue without messages in `catalog.operation_messages` table. 
I had only the row in `catalog.operations` table, referred to the deploy.

Today googling the web I found that it might be a memory issue.
In the log mentioned before, I got those messages (see below) at the exact time when I deployed my integration... and WOW! I realized that my VM box has **2GB (total amount of RAM)**, 1GB maximum mem for ms sql server...  :(

This is a machine that we are using only for SSIS management and test purpose, ...anyway do you think that 2GB for the machine and 1GB for the server are enough?

**Today I tried again the deploy and luckily (or randomly) it worked, with the same amount of ram and with same messages** (fewer than yesterday for the same deploy).

```
01/17/2018 15:25:10,spid22s,Unknown,AppDomain 5 (SSISDB.dbo[runtime].4) unloaded.
01/17/2018 15:25:09,spid14s,Unknown,AppDomain 5 (SSISDB.dbo[runtime].4) is marked for unload due to memory pressure.
01/17/2018 15:24:54,spid69,Unknown,Unsafe assembly 'microsoft.sqlserver.integrationservices.server<c/> version=11.0.0.0<c/> culture=neutral<c/> publickeytoken=89845dcd8080cc91<c/> processorarchitecture=msil' loaded into appdomain 5 (SSISDB.dbo[runtime].4).
01/17/2018 15:24:54,spid69,Unknown,Unsafe assembly 'microsoft.sqlserver.integrationservices.server<c/> version=11.0.0.0<c/> culture=neutral<c/> publickeytoken=89845dcd8080cc91<c/> processorarchitecture=msil' loaded into appdomain 5 (SSISDB.dbo[runtime].4).
01/17/2018 15:24:54,spid69,Unknown,AppDomain 5 (SSISDB.dbo[runtime].4) created.

01/16/2018 17:25:07,spid27s,Unknown,AppDomain 4 (SSISDB.dbo[runtime].3) unloaded.
01/16/2018 17:25:06,spid27s,Unknown,AppDomain 4 (SSISDB.dbo[runtime].3) is marked for unload due to memory pressure.
01/16/2018 17:24:03,spid69,Unknown,Unsafe assembly 'microsoft.sqlserver.integrationservices.server<c/> version=11.0.0.0<c/> culture=neutral<c/> publickeytoken=89845dcd8080cc91<c/> processorarchitecture=msil' loaded into appdomain 4 (SSISDB.dbo[runtime].3).
01/16/2018 17:24:03,spid69,Unknown,Unsafe assembly 'microsoft.sqlserver.integrationservices.server<c/> version=11.0.0.0<c/> culture=neutral<c/> publickeytoken=89845dcd8080cc91<c/> processorarchitecture=msil' loaded into appdomain 4 (SSISDB.dbo[runtime].3).
01/16/2018 17:24:03,spid69,Unknown,AppDomain 4 (SSISDB.dbo[runtime].3) created.

01/16/2018 17:24:02,spid15s,Unknown,AppDomain 3 (SSISDB.dbo[runtime].2) unloaded.
01/16/2018 17:24:02,spid15s,Unknown,AppDomain 3 (SSISDB.dbo[runtime].2) is marked for unload due to memory pressure.
01/16/2018 17:23:57,spid69,Unknown,Unsafe assembly 'microsoft.sqlserver.integrationservices.server<c/> version=11.0.0.0<c/> culture=neutral<c/> publickeytoken=89845dcd8080cc91<c/> processorarchitecture=msil' loaded into appdomain 3 (SSISDB.dbo[runtime].2).
01/16/2018 17:23:57,spid69,Unknown,Unsafe assembly 'microsoft.sqlserver.integrationservices.server<c/> version=11.0.0.0<c/> culture=neutral<c/> publickeytoken=89845dcd8080cc91<c/> processorarchitecture=msil' loaded into appdomain 3 (SSISDB.dbo[runtime].2).
01/16/2018 17:23:57,spid69,Unknown,AppDomain 3 (SSISDB.dbo[runtime].2) created.
```

Answer (score 0):

Now this message is quite useful as it provides information that I can use to fix the issue. This SSIS Project contains a date parameter BackDate, which I had not set. Here’s the parameter.

SSISVSParameters

I set this parameter to date between 1/1/1753 and 12/31/9999 and deployed the project again. This time, no error.

I hope that you have found this post helpful, especially if you haven’t deployed a package to SSIS in SQL Server 2012 or later.

https://www.desertislesql.com/wordpress1/?p=1140